# How to inspect logs for requests sent to IAM (Web) Identity Providers (OIDC/SAML) in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I often assume IAM roles with a web identities, to generated temporary AWS credentials, as follows:

```
aws sts assume-role-with-web-identity --role-arn <arn> --role-session-name <name> --web-identity-token <token>
```

The issue is that I sometimes get cryptic errors that might relate  to an invalid audience etc.

How can I view the logs of requests sent to IAM identity providers to pinpoint isses, like inspecting received JWTs etc?